# Does something change in a magnet when an electron crosses its lines?

Tags: magnetic-fields, quantum-spin

An electron can cross the magnetic field of a steady magnet and flip its spin. What changes in the body of the magnet? Does some electron inside flip its spin opposite to that of the passing electron and if so, does it diminish the magnetic field of this magnet?

Answer (score 1):

> An electron can cross the magnetic field of a steady magnet and flip its spin. What changes in the body of the magnet?

In permanent magnets a remarkable part of the subatomic particles is aligned with their magnetic dipoles and form the macroscopic magnetic field.
If you move another permanent magnet towards the first one, the alignment of electrons is intensified in both magnets. Strictly speaking, the common magnetic field of both magnets is stronger than the sum of the fields before the approach. This has to do with the - in sum better - alignment of the electrons to the common magnetic field of the magnet.
Secondly, when the magnets have moved away again, the additionally aligned electrons - which are trapped in their atomic and molecular bonds - are pushed back into their old orientations. The magnetic fields of the two magnets remain at the same strength as before.

What does this have to do with your topic. A single electron has a intrinsic magnetic dipole, it is a tiny magnet. Probably the electrons diplle is oriented in random direction and corssing the permanent magnet, it gets aligned. On the over hand it „helps“ the electrons inside the magnetic material, to get aligned stronger in the common direction of the macroscopic magnetic field.

> Does some electron inside flip its spin opposite to that of the passing electron and if so, does it diminish the magnetic field of this magnet?

From the above said it is clear that usually nothing flips because of the strong atomic and molecular bonds. In sum the orientation of the electrons show more in the direction of the common field. The magnetic field amplifyes.

From your comments:

> ... the electron is strictly regarded as pointlike and there is no rotation when its spin changes. It flips from say -1/2 to +1/2. I am not even sure that it changes spin z-component or is just projected on -1/2 or +1/2. But then also all electrons inside the magnet must be projected in regard to the electrons magnetic field.

The numbers you mentioned are introduced to show the orientation of electrons in atoms. For example, the two electrons in Helium have an antiparallel orientation of their magnetic dipoles, expressed by -1/2 and +1/2. And for a free heliom atom both electrons together can be spatial oriented randomly.
In a aggregation the termic movement of the atoms and molecules prevents the self-alignment of teh magnetic dipoles. Under some circumstances - near 0 Kelvin and not as a solid as a starting point - the self-alignemnt works and you get a BEC.

So it is not enough of a single electron, crossing a material, to influence all the electrons to „be projected in regard to the electrons magnetc field“.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler Thank you very much for your answer. I come here a little bit late for some reasons, sorry.
Well I understand your point of view.
But what follows from it is:
1. the free passing electron spin flips
2. the electrons in the magnet orient more or less in the new common field
3. the free electron goes away and  the magnets electrons return back to their previous orientations.

The results are: 
1. the spin of the free electron is changed, which needs  some energy which is sort of h/2
2. the magnet remains unaltered. So no change in Energy.

The conserv. law is broken?

Comment: @Mercury The energy comes from the kinetic energy of the incoming electron. It leaves the „battle field“ with less speed.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler That's good, but the speed can be made infinitesimally small.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler. It also must rotate the magnet as the answer of SuperCiocia indicates. That is some more energy wasted from the kinetic term.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler Also one object (the magnet) interacts with another (the electron). One remains not changed, the other changes. This is against Newtons Third low.

Comment: @Mercury In analogy if you throw a ball towards a wall, the balls parameters (the direction) changes, the other remains.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler but if the ball is from lead it will break a hole. So in this case if I let through the magnet zillions of electrons there must be an observable effect in the magnet, which will stay forever.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler by the way the impulse of the wall has to change P=2p; where p is the impulse of the photon. Of course its speed will change so little it could not be observed because of the mass.

Answer (score 0):

The magnet generates a magnetic field $\mathbf{B}_{\text{magnet}}$. The electron has a dipole moment $\mathbf{m}_{\text{electron}}$ due to its spin, which will experience a torque $\boldsymbol{\tau}$:
$$ \boldsymbol{\tau}_{\text{on electron}} = \mathbf{m}_{\text{electron}} \times \mathbf{B}_{\text{magnet}}. $$

By Newton's third law, the electron itself will also exert a torque on the whole magnet:
$$ \boldsymbol{\tau}_{\text{on magnet}} = \mathbf{M}_{\text{magnet}} \times \mathbf{B}_{\text{electron}}, $$
where $\mathbf{B}_{\text{electron}}$ is the field generated by the electron's spin, and $\mathbf{M}_{\text{magnet}}$ is the magnetic dipole moment of the whole magnet.

Torque goes as inertia, which goes as mass. Since the magnet is probably much more massive than the electron, the torque on the magnet is negligible. The only visible effet is then the electron flipping its orientation until its spin is parallel to the magnetic field of the magnet.

Comment: I can agree with this if there was a macroscopic object instead the electron. But the electron is strictly regarded as pointlike and there is no rotation when its spin changes. It flips from say -1/2 to +1/2. I am not even sure that it changes spin z-component or is just projected on -1/2 or +1/2. But then also all electrons inside the magnet must be projected in regard to the electrons magnetic field.

Comment: And by the way I am not even sure that the magnetic field of the electron (which is very weak) would reach to the magnet if there is some distance over 1 cm or even much less.